# How to retrieve a list of maps from firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on my project in flutter and I'm stuck in kind of a dumb problem. I'd like to retrieve a List of maps from Firebase, but i can't convert the document in an object format.

So every checkout document is identified by the user email. As a consequence every document will contain a list of checkout orders as displayed in the picture.

[This is the Document format in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kanyo.png)

```
class UserCheckoutOrderList extends Equatable {
   final String checkoutOrderDate;
   final Map<dynamic, dynamic> customerAddress;
   final String customerName;
   final String customerPhone;
   final String deliveryFee;
   final String subTotal;
   final String total;
   final List<Product> products;

   const UserCheckoutOrderList(
            {required this.checkoutOrderDate,
             required this.customerAddress,
             required this.customerName,
             required this.customerPhone,
             required this.deliveryFee,
             required this.subTotal,
             required this.total,
             required this.products});

  static UserCheckoutOrderList fromSnapshot(List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshots) {
final ordersList = snapshots.forEach((snapshot) {
  return  UserCheckoutOrderList(
      checkoutOrderDate: snapshot['checkoutOrderDate'],
      customerAddress: snapshot['customerAddress'],
      customerName: snapshot['customerName'],
      customerPhone: snapshot['customerPhone'],
      deliveryFee: snapshot['deliveryFee'],
      subTotal: snapshot['subTotal'],
      total: snapshot['total'],
      products: snapshot['products']);
});
return ordersList;
}

@override
List<Object?> get props => [];
}
```

This is what I've tried so far for the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend to always have an id on any document. This is how to handle data:

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

@immutable
class UserCheckoutOrderListEntity extends Equatable{
  final String id;
  final String checkoutOrderDate;
  final Map customerAddress;
  final String customerName;
  final String customerPhone;
  final String deliveryFee;
  final String subTotal;
  final String total;
  final List products;


  const UserCheckoutOrderListEntity({
      required this.id,
      required this.checkoutOrderDate,
      required this.customerAddress,
      required this.customerName,
      required this.customerPhone,
      required this.deliveryFee,
      required this.subTotal,
      required this.total,
      required this.products});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'checkoutOrderDate': checkoutOrderDate,
      'customerAddress': customerAddress,
      'customerName': customerName,
      'customerPhone': customerPhone,
      'deliveryFee': deliveryFee,
      'subTotal': subTotal,
      'total': total,
      'products': products,
    };
  }

  factory UserCheckoutOrderListEntity.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return UserCheckoutOrderListEntity(
      id: map['id'] as String,
      checkoutOrderDate: map['checkoutOrderDate'] as String,
      customerAddress: map['customerAddress'] as Map,
      customerName: map['customerName'] as String,
      customerPhone: map['customerPhone'] as String,
      deliveryFee: map['deliveryFee'] as String,
      subTotal: map['subTotal'] as String,
      total: map['total'] as String,
      products: map['products'] as List,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [id];
}
```

Then in your widget:

```
class CheckOut extends StatelessWidget {
  const CheckOut({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<UserCheckoutOrderListEntity>>(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("orderCheckOut")
            .get()
            .then((query) => query.docs
                .map((map) => UserCheckoutOrderListEntity.fromMap(map.data()))
                .toList()),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Container();
        });
  }
}
```